# keeping DateTime.Now.timeofday.tostring() updated while app is running

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datetime

Here's my Problem when I start the app. for example at 3:00 PM and I use the `DateTime.Now.timeofday.tostring()` and output it, it calls out 3:00 PM, but after waiting 5 mins (3:05) without closing the app, I still get the same output (3:00). how do I make sure that the time is always up to date without having to close the app.???

Comment: what laguage are you using? any way, you well need to use a thread.

Comment: @elyashiv it's on the tags.

Comment: If you check the value of DateTime.Now again it would reflect the correct time. Can you please post a code snippet to show what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

To get current time you may use either

`DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()`

or

`DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()`

It will get updated properly.